# Is this notation correct?

Tags: syntax, uml, diagramming

[image]
I have seen the following notation which goes against what I have learnt.
On the picture, the red line is where I thought it should be as the decision must be made and the path goes from the diamond shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision "takes place" in the decision node, so the path must come from there, it is not correct to "make a decision" outside a decision node (at least not in any UML Diagram I know of, purely academic background). What type of diagram does that notation appear in?

Comment: Thank you, it is an activity diagram with swimlanes.

Comment: In that case, I am certain (within my knowledge) that the notation you see in the picture is wrong. Control flows are always triggered when the source activity is finished, regardless of conditions being met. If that "Not" label is trying to express that after the activity ended a decision to follow one direction or another had to be made, and that "Not" is a possible result of this decision, then that path should definitely depart from the diamond decision node and not from the activity itself.

In addition, the guard usually goes withing brackets.